# How to create vertical infinity carouse only with CSS?

Tags: css, animation, slider, carousel

I'm trying to create infinity css vertical carousel using keyframes, but in the result there are a big delay (space) between items and on the second run (loop) items overlapping each other. But the items should go one after another and the simultaneously should be visible only three item lik one image. The item which is in the center should have opacity 1, text opacity 1 and image color red.
Maybe you can assist with the following problem?

Here is the code.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="new-style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="new-style.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="carousel">
            <div class="carousel__items-container">
              <!-- Duplicate elements for infinite carousel -->
              <div class="carousel__item">
                <div class="carousel__item-body">
                  <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img alt="regulatory" class="image" src="images/reg.png" />
                  </div>
                  <p class="title">regulatory</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="carousel__item">
                <div class="carousel__item-body">
                  <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img alt="automative" class="image" src="images/auto.png" />
                  </div>
                  <p class="title">automative</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="carousel__item">
                <div class="carousel__item-body">
                  <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img alt="finances" class="image" src="images/fin.png" />
                  </div>
                  <p class="title">finances</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="carousel__item">
                <div class="carousel__item-body">
                  <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img alt="commodities" class="image" src="images/com.png" />
                  </div>
                  <p class="title">commodities</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="carousel__item">
                <div class="carousel__item-body">
                  <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img
                      alt="healthcare"
                      class="image"
                      src="images/health.png"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <p class="title">healthcare</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="carousel__item">
                <div class="carousel__item-body">
                  <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img
                      alt="engineering"
                      class="image"
                      src="images/engin.png"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <p class="title">engineering</p>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="carousel__item">
                <div class="carousel__item-body">
                  <div class="image-wrapper">
                    <img alt="telcom" class="image" src="images/telcom.png" />
                  </div>
                  <p class="title">telcom</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </body>
</html>
```

AND CSS

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Work Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, #420285, #08bdbd);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 10px;
}

.carousel__item {
  display: flex;

  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 370px;
  height: 92px;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  -webkit-animation: vertical 21s linear infinite;
  animation: vertical 21s linear infinite;
  /* margin: 100px 0; */
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .carousel__item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.carousel__item-body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 92px;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-radius: 20px;

  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: color 8s linear infinite;
  animation: color 8s linear infinite;
  translate: all 0.3s ease;
}

.title {
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  /* line-height: 42px; */
  letter-spacing: -1.08px;
}

.image-wrapper {
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 62px;
  height: 62px;
  background-color: #fff; /* Set initial background color */
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-animation: color 15s linear infinite;
  animation: color 15s linear infinite;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: calc(4s * -1);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(4s * 0);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(4s * 1);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: calc(4s * 2);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(4s * 3);
}

.carousel__item:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: calc(4s * 4);
}

.carousel__item:last-child {
  animation-delay: calc(-4s * 2);
}





/* @keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%) scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  3%,
  14.28571428577% {
    transform: translateY(100%) scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.4;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  17.2857142857%,
  28.5714285714% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(0.8);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  31.5714285714%,
  42.8571428571% {
    transform: translateY(-100%) scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.4;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  45.8571428571% {
    transform: translateY(-100%) scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-150%) scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}  */



@keyframes vertical {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(250%);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  

  14.28571428577% {
    transform: translateY(200%);
    opacity: 0.4;
    visibility: visible;
  }

  28.5714285714% {
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
 
  42.8571428571% {
    transform: translateY(-160%);
    opacity: 0.4;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  45.8571428571% {
    transform: translateY(-200%);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-250%);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
} 





/* @keyframes color {
  28.5714285714% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

I have tried to change animation-delay and keyframes but the result was the same.

Comment: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-a-css-only-infinite-scroll-animation